# How to create a dynamic sql query to update table columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Hello I created a dynamic sql query but there are errors encountered on it saying column names could not be bound. Here's my code.

```
SET @query =  N' UPDATE hl  
SET ' + STUFF(hl.Fruit1, 13, 1, CAST(@i AS CHAR)) + ' = '''' + l.Name, + ''''
' + STUFF(hl.Color1, 18, 1, CAST(@i AS CHAR)) + ''' = l.Color, ''' +
STUFF(hl.Size1, 9, 1, CAST(@i AS VARCHAR)) + ''' = l.Size, ''' + 
STUFF(hl.Origin1, 13, 1, CAST(@i AS CHAR)) + ''' = l.location1, ''' +
STUFF(hl.Destination1, 14, 1, CAST(@i AS CHAR)) + ''' = l.location2, ''' + '
FROM #Fruits hl
INNER JOIN #Catalog l
ON hl.Id = old.id
WHERE  l.Name = ''' + @FruitName +''''
        
EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

Thanks for the help guys,

Comment: Put your code into the question as *text*.  Also provide a database tag.

Comment: okay gordon wait.

Comment: Hi again james adam, done adding the code.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: hello adam already fix it. its just data type i need to change it to string. :) thanks for you quick response :)